# Using Praw how do you get comment linked by a URL

Tags: python, api, reddit

I am trying to get the content linked to by a reddit URL, it could be a submission OR a comment, and I need to be able to get the corresponding object, does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did it a bit of a hacky way:

```
def getObjectFromLink(url):
    global r
    obj=praw.objects.Submission.get_info(r, url)
    if len(url.split('/'))==6:
        return obj
    else:
        return obj.comments[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PRAW (it seems you are from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12465878/176978)) you can simply use the `get_submission` function for either case.

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit('<USER AGENT>')
submission = r.get_submission('http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/10msc8/how_to_calculate_more_comments_count_not_just/')
comment = r.get_submission('http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/10msc8/how_to_calculate_more_comments_count_not_just/c6euu6b').comments[0]
```

To get the comment, we're using the permalink to the comment which returns the json data for the submission, along with the data for the comment and its children. However, in this case the comment tree will only have a single top-level comment thus `comments[0]` is the desired comment.