# Reddit api return the content of a comment or a self.text

Tags: reddit

After looking at the documentation I still can't understand how it's all tied up.  What I am trying to accomplish is simple: given an url, return the text contents of that url.

For example:

```
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='my_cool_app')


post  = "http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/10kp2h\
         /lots_of_people_dont_feel_identified_or_find/"
comment = "http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/10kp2h\
           /lots_of_people_dont_feel_identified_or_find/c6ec6hf"
```

Establishing which is a comment and which is a post can be done using regex but if there's a better way I will use that.

So my question is: what is the best way to determine the nature of a reddit url and how do I get the contents of that url?

What I tried so far:

```
post=praw.objects.Submission.get_info(r, url).selftext 
#returns the self.text of a post regardless if that url is a permalink to a comment

comment_text = praw.objects.?????() # how to do this ?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit('<USERAGENT>')
comment_url = ('http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/10kp2h'
               '/lots_of_people_dont_feel_identified_or_find/c6ec6hf')
comment = r.get_submission(comment_url).comments[0]
print comment.body
```

My responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463818/using-praw-how-do-you-get-comment-linked-by-a-url/12738719#12738719) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719542/decoding-json-from-reddit-api-in-python-using-praw/12738636#12738636) should provide additional useful information related to your question.

Comment: Thx , but i found my way trough the documentation , but none the less thx for helping me . Have an epic day .